# how to keep google login session alive till user manually logout in ionic 4 + angular mobile app?

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-plus, ionic4

I created ionic4 application in which i am trying to backup user data in user's google drive.
For that I implemented google login with google drive scope, but `accessToken` gets expired after some time.
Application don't have any backend services. So I want to schedule backup to google drive in my app for that i need to keep google login token alive.
Can we do that using cordova google plus plugin ?

Can you please add example of how to keep google session alive ?

I am getting following response after google login.

> accessToken: "My-access-token"
>
> displayName: "Abc xyz"
>
> email: "abc@gmail.com"
>
> expires: 1564411539
>
> expires_in: 3191
>
> familyName: "Abc"
>
> givenName: "Xyz"
>
> idToken: "my-id-token"
>
> imageUrl: "my-gmail-profile-pic-utl"
>
> serverAuthCode: "my-login-servcer-auth-code"
>
> userId: "1608XXXXXXXXXXXX030XX"

Answer (score 1):

So i solved this issue. 
You can use firebase with google login and firebase will automatically refresh your access_token when it expires.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution???

Comment: I created google session token and stored it in firebase and then firebase manages it. So it refreshes the token automatically.